# Redirect user if has certain value in database

Tags: php, html, sql

Hi so on my website I have this Maintenance mode that I can activate by changing the value in the SQL from 0 to 1, it will redirect all user to a specific page. I want to do the same but for a specific user. So I added a column to my SQL called Banned with a default value of 0. I tried to copy the code for the maintenance but no success.

Code for the maintenance:

```
 <?php
include 'config.php';

if (isset($_COOKIE['hash'])) {
    $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `hash` = " . $db->quote(filter_var($_COOKIE['hash'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));
    if ($sql->rowCount() != 0) {
        $row = $sql->fetch();
        $user = $row;
    }
}


$sql22 = $db->query('SELECT websiteOnline FROM website WHERE websiteOnline = 0');
if($sql22->rowCount() == 1 && $user['rank'] != 69)
{
    header('Location: maintenance.php'); 
}
```

[SQL Banned Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmW7D.jpg)

My code for a specific user:

```
     <?php
    include 'config.php';

    if (isset($_COOKIE['hash'])) {
        $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `hash` = " . $db->quote(filter_var($_COOKIE['hash'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));
        if ($sql->rowCount() != 0) {
            $row = $sql->fetch();
            $user = $row;
        }
    }


    $sql22 = $db->query('SELECT websiteOnline FROM website WHERE websiteOnline = 0');
    if($sql22->rowCount() == 1 && $user['rank'] != 69)
    {
        header('Location: maintenance.php'); 
    }

$sql22 = $db->query('SELECT Banned FROM users WHERE Banned = 0');
    if($sql22->rowCount() == 1 && $user['rank'] != 69)
    {
        header('Location: banned.php'); 
    }
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem? What error are you facing?

Comment: Well it just does not work @LukasMeine. When I set the banned to 1 I’m not being redirected like the maintenance code would do.

Comment: That's because you are selecting users that are not banned. did you try selecting banned users? SELECT Banned FROM users WHERE Banned != 0'

Comment: it would also be nice if you check if the current user is the banned user. If you don't, every user would be redirected if a single user was banned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also think that you are using the cookie hash to determine what user is logged in, and i would like to try a different aproach. You already have all the info about the user on the $user variable, so, no need for a third query.

```
//here you already have everything about the user, so no need for a third query
    if (isset($_COOKIE['hash'])) {
    $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `hash` = " . $db->quote(filter_var($_COOKIE['hash'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));
    if ($sql->rowCount() != 0) {
        $row = $sql->fetch();
        $user = $row;
        }
    }

    //This seems to work, so ok, leave it.
    $sql22 = $db->query('SELECT websiteOnline FROM website WHERE websiteOnline = 0');
    if($sql22->rowCount() == 1 && $user['rank'] != 69)
    {
        header('Location: maintenance.php');
        exit(); //just to make sure anything else wont run if the user just cancels the redirect
    }

    //Now we check if the user is banned. removed the type comparison because if $user['banned'] was a string, things would not work
    if($user['banned'] != 0 && $user['rank'] != 69)
    {
      header('Location: banned.php');
      exit(); //just to make sure anything else wont run if the user just cancels the redirect
    }
```

Comment: This seem to work but I don't have a second account to check if it affect all user or only the banned user

Comment: it will affect only the banned user, unless all the other users on the database have the exact same hash.

Comment: Look like it affect all the user. Just tried with another person. See for your self. Here is my site https://csgofullcasino.com

Comment: 0 means the user is banned or not banned?

Comment: 0 mean not banned. 1 mean banned

Comment: hmmm, guess its a type comparison mistake then. just updated my answear, try again.

Comment: Just want to tell you that rank 69 is admin and should not be affected by it.

Comment: if it still doesn't work, do a var_dump($user['banned']);  and tell me what happened.

Comment: the user will only be redirected if rank is different than 69.

Comment: Ok even when it set to 0 I get redirected to banned.php, but if I have the rank 69 it does not apply.

Comment: did you try removing the second '=' on $user['banned'] !== just like my updated answer did? remove it and make sure it looks like this $user['banned'] !=

Comment: Ok so my site is working but I saw on your profile that you know stuff about NodeJS. In my app I get this error in the console: 
[2017-10-26 01:14:07.968] [DEBUG] [default] - Tradeoffer #2622416785 (sent - joinJackpot) with code : 6sOVQB has been created by steamid: 76561198114317007
(node:8449) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:8449) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are using the hash to determine if the user is logged in, that the value of 0 means banned, and that the problem you are facing is that the user who logs in and is banned is not being redirected to the banned page.

I'm not sure which method you are using to connect to the db, so I'm going to leave some of it in comments that you have to fill in yourself.

Your previous code is simply checking for banned = 0 in the database, and if the number of records that is are banned is 1, then it'll simply forward all users to the banned page.

You need to check if that particular user is banned, and if so, forward that user to the banned page.

Hope that I understood the question correctly and helped you in your answer :)

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['hash'])) {
$sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `hash` = " . $db->quote(filter_var($_COOKIE['hash'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));
if ($sql->rowCount() != 0) {
    $row = $sql->fetch();
    $user = $row;
    }
}


$sql22 = $db->query('SELECT websiteOnline FROM website WHERE websiteOnline = 0');
if($sql22->rowCount() == 1 && $user['rank'] != 69)
{
    header('Location: maintenance.php'); 
}
$sql22 = $db->query('SELECT Banned FROM users WHERE Banned = 0 AND hash=:hash');

//bind the value of cookie to :hash here,
//execute the query

if($sql22->rowCount() == 1 && $user['rank'] != 69)
{
    header('Location: banned.php'); 
}
```

Comment: To access my database I’m using phpmyadmin, also I’m not to sure what to do here //bind the value of cookie to :hash here,
//execute the query